# MYSQL: How to check exit status?

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, ubuntu, remote-access

I've a problem with mysql remote connections. One server located in USA, the other located in Netherlands and the connection between them is horrible, especially in the evenings.

I managed to solve the `select` query by setting a timeout

```
done < <(mysql --connect_timeout=10 --batch -e "${selectQ}" -u${user} -p${password} ${database} -h ${host})
```

but I don't know how to solve `update` query, as it should be send only once.

```
echo "UPDATE table set field='1' WHERE id='${id}'" | mysql -u${user} -p${password} ${database} -h ${host}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same way:

```
echo "UPDATE table set field='1' WHERE id='${id}'" | 
       mysql --connect_timeout=10 -u${user} -p${password} ${database} -h ${host}
```

in order to check the results, here's an example:

```
myhost:~ # echo "silly query;"|mysql -unoone -pwrong DBEMPTY -hlocalhost
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'noone'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
myhost:~ # echo $?
1
myhost:~ # echo "select 0;"|mysql -uvaliduser -pproperpassword MYTESTDB -hlocalhost
0
0
myhost:~ # echo $?
0
```

Comment: and why do you sure it will be successfully sent?

Comment: As always you need to check the exit code of mysql and the output whether the result is proper and the expected one.

Comment: it'll be nice if you could give an example of how you do that in bash.