# Bash Linux - Test if mysql command succsfully executed

Tags: mysql, bash, testing

i wrote a script that make a dump of mysql dbs, i need to check if the command succfully executed or not. using $? give me always 0 even if there are a connection problem with the db server.
any idea how can i do this
thanks

Comment: Please show us your code, as it seems that `mysql` does provide a valid exit status... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369396/mysql-how-to-check-exit-status

Comment: mysqldump -u usr -ppwd db | gzip -c > db.sql.g
echo $? # test exit status

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Script

```
#!/bin/sh
mysqldump -h 192.168.1.10 -u user -pPaSSwOrD dbname > filename.sql
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Error"
fi
```

is successfully showing errors for connection timeouts, wrong dbname, wrong username and password. It only doesn't check integrity of dump taken, but it's another story.

Comment: thanks Shader, the problem was that i am using a pipe after the mysql command to compress the output 'mysqldump -u usr -ppwd db | gzip -c > db.sql.gz' so i think that the result of $?  concern the gzip command status not the first mysql one. that's it ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If we change the first line to `mysqldump -h 192.168.1.10 -u user -pPaSSwOrD dbname | gzip > filename.sql.gz`, then $? is referencing to gzip operation. To make it easier, split operation in two: make a dump (and check if it's successful), compress it to .gz (and check if necessary).

Comment: Other solution is to put `set -o pipefail` before `mysqldump ... | gzip > ...`. In this case pipe will return an error if any of command fails.

Comment: thanks again, this last one resolve the problem to me.